# How to brute force arithmetic puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, math

A friend shared this puzzle:

> How to make 21 from the numbers 1, 5, 6, 7?
>
> You can use the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, as well as brackets. You must use each number once.

I eventually solved it on paper—two days later. No doubt a computer could brute force all solutions in a second.

How though? I tried generating all strings `a.b.c.d` inserting the numbers for letters and operations for dots, but it missed my solution.

---

Bonus puzzles:

- How to make 11 from 1,5,6,7?
- How to make 16 from 1,5,6,7?

Comment: And what would be the answer for 21? (I can't seem to find it)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that [this python code](http://ideone.com/aTiMHK) implements AnT's algorithm. And I find no results for `16` or `21`.

Comment: Are you allowing nonsense like `15 + 67`?

Comment: @BillLynch By always putting `value` into the left, it's missing, e.g., `1-(5+6)`.

Comment: If anyone is interested, `6/(1 - 5/7) = 21`.

Comment: `11 = 6*(7-5)-1` and `16 = 67 - 51`.

Comment: This could be considered as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461084/how-to-find-the-exact-set-of-operations-for-a-specific-number (although the details may vary, of course)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An obvious approach would be the folllwing:

1. You start with a vector `S` of four numbers: `S = ( 1, 5, 6, 7 )`
2. Pick any two numbers `a` and `b` from `S`, remove them from `S`
3. Apply an arbitrary arithmetic operation to `a` and `b`, thus obtaining a new number `c` (take care to avoid division by zero and verify exact division, if the problem requires it)
4. Include `c` into `S`, thus obtaining `S'`
5. Continue from step 1, now using `S'` in place of `S`

Brute-force branching is performed at step 2 (selecting two numbers), and step 3 (selecting operation). The cycle should be repeated until `S` reduces to only 1 element, which is the result for this particular brute-force branch.

Brackets are not used explicitly, but they are present implicitly.

If one branch ends with `21` in `S`, you have a solution, at which point you can either terminate, or continue branching to search for other solutions.

Comment: Cool. That's exactly the algorithm I ended up writing. You explain it clearly. https://gist.github.com/hickford/56cc7e2b0c55c140a976

Answer (score 2):

Here's the "pop two, combine, recurse" algorithm as suggested by AnT, coded in Python. The hardest part was assembling the expressions after the recursion. I used find-and-replace.

```
#!python
import operator
import itertools
from fractions import Fraction

operations = dict()
operations['+'] = operator.add
operations['-'] = operator.sub
operations['/'] = operator.truediv
operations['*'] = operator.mul

def solve(target, numbers):
    """List ways to make target from numbers."""
    numbers = [Fraction(x) for x in numbers]
    return solve_inner(target, numbers)

def solve_inner(target, numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        if numbers[0] == target:
            yield str(target)
        return

    # combine a pair of numbers with an operation, then recurse
    for a,b in itertools.permutations(numbers, 2):
        for symbol, operation in operations.items():
            try:
                product = operation(a,b)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                continue

            subnumbers = list(numbers)
            subnumbers.remove(a)
            subnumbers.remove(b)
            subnumbers.append(product)

            for solution in solve_inner(target, subnumbers):
                # expand product (but only once)
                yield solution.replace(str(product), "({0}{1}{2})".format(a, symbol, b), 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [1, 5, 6, 7]
    target = 21
    solutions = solve(target, numbers)
    for solution in solutions:
        print("{0}={1}".format(target, solution))
```

Solutions to the three puzzles:

```
>>> solve(21,[1,5,6,7])
6/(1-(5/7))
>>> solve(11,[1,5,6,7])
(6*(7-5))-1
((7-5)*6)-1
>>> solve(16,[1,5,6,7])
[]
```

(The third puzzle is impossible)