# How do I solve this mathematical problem using python?

Tags: python

I have a question that was asked of me:

> Form a given number using only 4s(**using the least number of 4s**) using only the following operations:
>
> 1. Addition
> 2. Subtraction
> 3. Multiplication
> 4. Division
> 5. Power(^)
> 6. Square root
> 7. Factorial
> 8. Greatest integer function
>
> For example, 3 = 4-(4/4)

**I'm a complete newbie to python**. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: please format your question correctly and also please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu: From the question: "How do I approach this problem?". In other words, OP doesn't even know where to start, so what they have tried is probably irrelevant. Additionally, you do *see* the "new contributor tag, yes? People asking questions here for the first time should be given a fair bit of slack, and those who have been here a while can help out with formatting, like this ...

Comment: The example is invalid:  it contains a 2.  Is there an exception for exponents?

Comment: @DennisSparrow: I corrected it

Comment: @kuldeeepsinghsidhu:No progress at all.I don't how to format properly. I'm new.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: A [solution to a similar but not identical problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-expression-represent-number-using-single-digit/) may help.  Discussions of similar problems on Stack Overflow generally don't improve on a brute force search, that is generating all possible expressions with increasing numbers of 4s until one of them generates the target.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353375/how-to-brute-force-arithmetic-puzzle?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `math` library. 
Code:

```
from math import *
x =  4**2- sqrt(4)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
14.0
```

**Note: Power in python is `**`**